# Static website access of environmental variable: "process is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, eleventy, render.com

I have a static website developed through 11ty (Node based SSG), which contains a Contact form that sends a request to a nodemailer API with the data. Both are hosted on Render, as a Static Website and Web Service respectively, and they share a basic auth password which I've stored in each project as an environmental variable.

The Web Service accesses the variables just fine. However, the static website's event presents me with the error in the title "process" isn't defined, as in "process.env.VARIABLE_NAME" which is how I'm accessing them. I tried including a secret .env file in the project with the same key and including dotenv in the project, but no change.

I assume the nature of the static site is making it so the environmental variable isn't being processed/applied somehow. What possible steps could I be missing here?

**EDIT:** Although it seems it might be possible for me to do this through methods such as command line arguments (which then get injected into the code during the build process), that wouldn't work for my case since the password had to be secret in the generated source files. The dotenv package didn't work in my case. Finally, I've opted to discard this password-based authentication instead and simply use honeypot fields to prevent spam and CORS Origin headers in the API to control request source.

Comment: No Static website run on client side you cannot get process object.

Comment: @miemengniao Is there any way to utilize the process object during build time perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Your static site is running in a different context than your web service (which acts like a server). Since your static site is run from a users browser, it does not understand node-specific functionality like loading files or accessing your process environment.

Adding your password to your static site would also create a security risk, because a user could just see your password, take it, and run their own requests without any security your site may have.

A usual approach to this would be to create an API of your own that takes in a request from your static site and talks to the API directly or a technology stack that takes the page rendering to a server (like ServerSideRendering). This way, YOUR system takes care of calling the API while your users requests are restricted.

Comment: Thank you. None of the passwords are stored directly in the code, they're set up directly from the host service. I'm really just stuck on how I could possibly safely inject the variables into the build without exposing them. Something like using the environment variable only at build time, so that it's still within the hosting/building context.